# reversing values in two multimaps

Tags: c++

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// dwa 1
// dwa 4
// jeden 1
// jeden 2
// piec 5

int main() {

    multimap1<string,int>;
    multimap2<int,string>;

    return 0; 
}
```

For this code, how one can assign multimap 2 to multimap 1 and recieve expected input(commented section of the code)

Comment: Iterate multimap 1, and insert into multimap 2.  What's difficult?

Comment: yeah, but how can i insert <string,int> pair into <int,string> map?

Comment: @user2746475: `map.insert(make_pair(pair.second,pair.first))`, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Something like following :

```
  std::multimap<int,std::string> src;
  std::multimap<std::string,int> dst;

  std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), std::inserter(dst, dst.begin()), 
                           [] (const std::pair<int,std::string> &p) {
                           return std::pair<std::string,int>(p.second, p.first);
                           }
                         );
```

See **[HERE](http://ideone.com/0hN7lv)**